# iOS - Table view cell not rendering properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, cgrect

I have my own TableViewController and TableViewCell classes to show the data in the format I want. My custom TableViewCell has a 60x60 image view, title label and subtitle label. I have several instances of it set up in my storyboards and properly hooked up (I've checked many times). To fit these elements I've made my cells 70px in height.

My problem is when they're rendering (excepto in one of the views I have set up in storyboards) they're rendering at their normal 44px height and the image view is smaller than that, yet the labels show in the correct place, it's like the size is right just the border of the cell and the UIImageView are wrong. This happens even though when debugging it shows the frame of the cell to be 320x70.

Image on the left is the one that looks properly, and on the right is one of the views that appear wrong:

[image][image]

Comment: just a check: did u properly overload the method - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath?

Comment: No, I just set it in the storyboard, but if that's the case, why does one work and the other doesn't?

Comment: Just added the method, that fixed it. Still don't understand the exclusive nature of it (one working where the other doesn't when I don't implement it). Post an answer so I can accept :). Thank you.

Comment: Where did you set the height of the cell in storyboard? I would be curious to know if there is a way to fix your issue in storyboard also.

Comment: I just set it in the properties for the TableViewCell, but it seem to be overridden somehow by the method when it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my experience of the storyboard some behavior seems a bit unpredictable. I will recommend you to overload the method - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath instead.